# Create Multiple Tables in SQLite Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I am referring This [Tutorial](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2015/01/windowsphone-81-sqlite-how-to-store.html) to store data in SQLite database. I am Trying to add another table to the database called "Schools". But it throws an Exception as follows saying No such table: Schools.

[image]

Classes

```
public class Contacts
{
    //The Id property is marked as the Primary Key
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Gardient { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Contacts()
    {
        //empty constructor
    }
    public Contacts( string name, string age, string address, string school, string gardient, string phone_no, string latitude, string longitude)
    {

        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Address = address;
        School = school;
        Gardient = gardient;
        PhoneNumber = phone_no;
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}

  public class Schools
    {
        //The Id property is marked as the Primary Key
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string CreationDate { get; set; }
        public Schools()
        {
            //empty constructor
        }
        public Schools( string school,string latitude, string longitude)
        {

            School = school;
            Latitude = latitude;
            Longitude = longitude;
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

DatabaseHelperClass

```
   public class DatabaseHelperClass
    {
        SQLiteConnection dbConn;

        //Create Tabble 
        public async Task<bool> onCreate(string DB_PATH)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
                {
                    using (dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
                    {
                        dbConn.CreateTable<Schools>();
                        dbConn.CreateTable<Contacts>();

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void createtable()
        {
            SQLite.SQLiteConnection db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
            db.CreateTable<Schools>();
            db.CreateTable<Contacts>();
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When I try to enter data to Schools table through textboxes this exception throws. Data are entered to the Contacts table without any issue. I have found similar questions but non of them answered my issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is seems that you have created table when the app is already installed on your device or emulator.Just Uninstall your app and reinstall it.It will work.This is due to because all tables are created when you install your app first time.Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Have you use the same code for creating table in App.xaml.cs file in App() constructor?

Comment: That was the issue. I missed that part. thank you very much for the heads up.

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you..please mark as correct so that others can enjoy this too :)